# how to add checkbox column to Extjs Grid

Tags: gridview, checkbox, extjs

I have EXTjs grid. I want to know how to add the checkbox to the Extjs grid column.

in my datatable I'll get the value for the column 'Status'. it may br either true/false. so based on that it should show the checkbox column checked / unchecked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the sample [here](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html). It uses a Plugin called CheckBoxColumn (you will have to View Source and find the JS file.

Some example usage from the Plugin's file...

```
var checkColumn = new Ext.grid.CheckColumn({
   header: 'Indoor?',
   dataIndex: 'indoor',
   id: 'check',
   width: 55
});

// add the column to the column model
var cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([{
       header: 'Foo',
       ...
    },
    checkColumn
]);

// create the grid
var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    ...
    cm: cm,
    plugins: [checkColumn], // include plugin
    ...
});
```