# How to display a checkbox in Ext.grid.GridPanel?

Tags: ajax, extjs, checkbox, gridpanel

I need to display a checkbox for column "Active" and when I change the selection to be to able to make an ajax request, to update the database.

Some sample code will help me a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link: [Extjs Grid plugins](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html).
You can check sources for second grid.

Also you need listen 'selectionchange' event for selection model of the grid - so you'll have selected rows and then you can submit a request to server or whatever you need.

---

If you need specific column (not the first one) - you can check this link: [Checkbox in the grid](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/889238-how-get-checkbox-grid-panel)

---

And I think this is same here too: [how to add checkbox column to Extjs Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315843/how-to-add-checkbox-column-to-extjs-grid)

Answer (score 0):

This is example from one of my projects:

```
Ext.define('Magellano.view.news.List' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.newslist',

    store: 'News',
    remoteSort: false,

    dockedItems: [{
      xtype: 'toolbar',

      items: [{
        text: 'Online',
        id: 'online-button',
        enableToggle: true,
        icon: '/images/light-bulb.png',
        pressed: true,
        handler: onItemToggle 
      }, { text: 'Preview',
        id: 'preview-button',
        enableToggle: true,
        pressed: true
      }],

    initComponent: function() {
      this.selModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
        singleSelect: false,
        sortable: false,
        checkOnly: true
      });

      this.columns = [
        { text: '', width: 28, renderer: function(val) { return "<img src='/images/star-empty.png' height='16' width='16'></img>"}},
        { text: 'Date', width: 60, dataIndex: 'newstime', renderer: renderDate},
        { text: 'Agency', width: 60, dataIndex: 'agency',  renderer: function(val) { return val;}},
        { text: 'Category', width: 60, dataIndex: 'category',  renderer: function(val) { return val;}},
        { text: 'Title', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'title', 
          renderer: function(val) { return Ext.String.format('<b>{0}</b>', val); }
        }
      ];

          this.title = "News from " + Ext.Date.dateFormat(new Date(), "j M Y");
          this.callParent(arguments);
        }
}
```

The important part is that in the initComponent you create the selection model:

```
  this.selModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
    singleSelect: false,
    sortable: false,
    checkOnly: true
  });
```